# Why is it not possible to use the AsyncClient to login without using sync_to_async?

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

According to the [documentation about testing async functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#testing-asynchronous-code) in Django 3.1, it should be possible to simply await the async client methods in an async context without having to wrap it in `sync_to_async` or `database_sync_to_async` as it implements all methods. Is there a way around this?

The first request works, but the second and third do not.

```
class TestAsyncClient(TransactionTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.async_client = AsyncClient()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user("user_a@example.com", "passwd_a")

    async def test_async_login(self):
        """Use the async client to login without using sync_to_async"""

        request = await self.async_client.get("/")
        self.assertTrue(request)
        
        logged_in = await self.async_client.login(
            username="user_a@example.com", password="passwd_a"
        )
        self.assertTrue(logged_in)

        logged_in = await self.async_client.force_login(self.user)
        self.assertTrue(logged_in)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you get a response, not a request.

What evaluates to True, would be `response.ok`.

However, async_client.login is not an async method and does not send a request, same with force_login. They simply fake a session with a logged in user and are synchronous (with database access if your SESSION_STORE is ModelBackend).